# Count number of customers per brand

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm experimenting/learning Python with a data set containing customers information.

The DataFrame structure is the following (these are made up records):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cus_id' : [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999], 
                   'cus_brand_id' : ['ABCD_111', 'ABCD_222', 'EFG_333', 'EFG_444', 'H_555', 'IJ_666', 'IJ_777', 'IJ_888', 'K_999']})
print(df)

   cus_id cus_brand_id
0     111     ABCD_111
1     222     ABCD_222
2     333      EFG_333
3     444      EFG_444
4     555        H_555
5     666       IJ_666
6     777       IJ_777
7     888       IJ_888
8     999        K_999
```

As you can see, a customer can belong in one of the 5 following brands: `ABCD`, `EFG`, `H`, `IJ`, and `K`.

My **goal** is to count the number of customers in each brand. That is, I want to produce the following output table:

```
| ABCD | 2 |
| EFG  | 2 |
| H    | 1 |
| IJ   | 3 |
| K    | 1 |
```

This is a simplistic example but the real data set I'm working with follows the same structure. Specifically, each `cus_brand_id` entry begins with some capital letters, followed by an underscore, followed by some numbers.

One thing I tried is to use the `split` method on the `cus_brand_id` Series to isolate the brands from the ids but I don't know how to continue from here.

```
cus_brand = df['cus_brand_id'].str.split('_')
print(cus_brand)

0    [ABCD, 111]
1    [ABCD, 222]
2     [EFG, 333]
3     [EFG, 444]
4       [H, 555]
5      [IJ, 666]
6      [IJ, 777]
7      [IJ, 888]
8       [K, 999]
Name: cus_brand_id, dtype: object
```

Comment: Use the `groupby` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first extract the ones, with `.str[0]`:

```
>>> df['cus_brand_id'].str.split('_').str[0]
0    ABCD
1    ABCD
2     EFG
3     EFG
4       H
5      IJ
6      IJ
7      IJ
8       K
Name: cus_brand_id, dtype: object
```

So we can obtain the brand with:

```
df['brand'] = df['cus_brand_id'].str.split('_').str[0]
```

and count the number of customers with:

```
>>> df.groupby('brand')['cus_id'].count()
brand
ABCD    2
EFG     2
H       1
IJ      3
K       1
Name: cus_id, dtype: int64
```

or the number of *unique* customers with:

```
>>> df.groupby('brand')['cus_id'].nunique()
brand
ABCD    2
EFG     2
H       1
IJ      3
K       1
Name: cus_id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cus_id' : [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999], 
                   'cus_brand_id' : ['ABCD_111', 'ABCD_222', 'EFG_333', 'EFG_444', 'H_555', 'IJ_666', 'IJ_777', 'IJ_888', 'K_999']})

# new data frame with split value columns 
new = df["cus_brand_id"].str.split("_", n = 1, expand = True) 

df["brand"]= new[0] 

df["brand_id"]= new[1] 

# Dropping old cus_brand_id columns 
df.drop(columns =["cus_brand_id"], inplace = True)

# df display 
df.groupby(by='brand')['cus_id'].count()

Out [1]:
brand
ABCD    2
EFG     2
H       1
IJ      3
K       1
Name: cus_id, dtype: int64
```

#### EDIT:

*You can always add, after `.count()`,  `.to_frame()` to have the Dataframe layout instead of a Series. Or `to_dict()` to have a dictionary with the brands as key*